# Using break to stop the moving lines in java

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I am completely new to java and I have one problem I am trying to resolve. I am using ACM Library for my purpose. My goal is the following:

1. Move Label 1
2. Move Label 2
3. Compare label 1's and label 2's position (when the text hits and its on each other) "Using 'if' statement"
4. Once on top, stop it by using `break` statement.
5. Restart the cycle.

If someone could help me out by explaining how this can be implemented. That would be awesome. I am trying to learn. Thank you!

```
import acm.graphics.GLabel;
import acm.program.CommandLineProgram;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class Main extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run( )

    {
            int label1_xy = 50;
            int label2_xy = 200;

            GLabel label1 = new GLabel("Hello World.");
            add(label1, label1_xy,label1_xy);

            GLabel label2 = new GLabel("Goodbye World.");
            add(label2, label2_xy,label2_xy);

            while (true)
            {
            label1.move(10,10);
                pause(500);
            label2.move(-10,-10);
            break;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Move Label 1**
2. **Move Label 2**

You have done these two.

3. **Compare label 1's and label 2's position (when the text hits and its on each other) "Using 'if' statement"**
4. **Once on top, stop it by using break statement.**

You can compare the position of those two labels by trying to retrieve the "bound" of the object. example :

```
label1.move(10,10);
pause(500);
if (label1.getBounds().getX() == label2.getBounds().getX() 
     && label1.getBounds().getY() == label2.getBounds().getY()) {
    break;
} else {
    label2.move(-10,-10);
}
```

5. **Restart the cycle**

You can restart this by putting another while block for the `run()` code or maybe just call the `run()` (beware of the `StackOverflowError` here).